# Android determine screen sizes

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which should support multiple screens. For normal screen, I have set my layout inside a viewflipper so my icons won't be crowded. But what I want to do in a large screen is to put all of the icons in just a one layout without using viewflipper to take advantage of the screen.

Here's my layout for normal screen:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/lighterred"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<ViewFlipper 
android:id="@+id/mainFlipper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMainNote"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/slidetoleft" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibSymptoms"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/symptoms"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/symptoms" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibConditions"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/conditions"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/conditions" />
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibMedicalAssessment"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/medicalassessment"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/med_assessments" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibProfile"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/profile"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile" />

</LinearLayout> <!-- 2nd row -->


</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center" >


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibTests"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/tests"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/tests" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibTreatment"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/treatment"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/treatment" />


</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibSpecialists"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/specialists"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/specialists" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ibDisclaimer"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:text="@string/about"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/disclaimer" />

</LinearLayout> 


</LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

So how am I able to do it in large screen?

Thanks and regrads.

Comment: it is time for you to [learn the joy of Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: @FoamyGuy Is it compatible with 2.3?

Comment: if you use the compatability library that should come with your sdk (or you download it via the sdk manager)

Answer (score 2):

Preferably you would use the regular xml files and place them in the right folders (e.g. layout-xlarge) then you have a layout for smaller sizes and layouts for larger sizes.

Also programatically depending on which version of android you are outputting to you would use

```
getResources().getConfiguration()
```

and using that find if the device screen size is

```
SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
```

for xlarge screens (> 7inches)
or

```
SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
```

for large screens (between 4 inches and 7 inches)
the first boundry is not defined before HoneyComb (API 11+)
while the second boundry has problems on certain devices.

EDIT:
I agree with FoamyGuy fragments would be so much better, especially since you can control each fragments logic specifically (eg. create a layout for large screens and create a layout for fragment with small screens (if you want to use a view flipper) or just start a new fragment like a new activity as shown in the Fragment docs).

Comment: Yes, I put it in layout-xlarge folder. But I have only one java class for both normal and large screens.

Comment: are you populating them dynamically? or do you have all the buttons you want to use already in the layout pre prepared?